# How to use renderToStaticMarkup in NextJS server action

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, server-action

I'm attempting to use `renderToStaticMarkup` in a NextJS 13 server action to send the generated HTML via email.

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";
import { sendEmail } from "@/infra/email";
import { ResetPasswordEmail } from "@/infra/email/templates";
import { userRoutes } from "@/routes";

interface SendPasswordResetLink {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  passwordResetToken: string;
}

export const sendPasswordResetLink = async ({ email, firstName, passwordResetToken }: SendPasswordResetLink): Promise<void> => {
  const url = userRoutes.resetPassword.generateUrl(passwordResetToken);
  const subject = `Password reset`;
  const html = renderToStaticMarkup(<ResetPasswordEmail firstName={firstName} url={url} />);
  const result = await sendEmail({ html, subject, toEmail: email, toName: firstName });

  //... more code
};
```

However I'm getting the following error in the backend:
`Error:  × Expected '>', got 'firstName'`

And in VSCode I get red squigly lines and when I hover it says:
`'ResetPasswordEmail' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ResetPasswordEmail'?ts(2749)`

[image]

The `ResetPasswordEmail` component doesn't have any interactivity, and its filename ends in `.tsx`.

Any idea how I can fix this, or some other way to send HTML emails in server actions? Thanks!

Comment: What is the extension of the file with `sendPasswordResetLink` function?

Comment: I've tried with `.ts` and `.tsx` and I get the same error in both.

Answer (score 0):

the error may be caused by nodejs not recognizing JSX syntax. try use React.createElement instead.

```
const element = React.createElement(ResetPasswordEmail, {firstName, url})
const html = renderToStaticMarkup(element)
```

suggestion:

Since you're using NextJS for SSR, maybe it's better to let NextJS  handle the rendering, then you can make request to NextJS server to get the rendered HTML and send it by email.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is likely due to a **TypeScript** type **error**.

When you use the `<ResetPasswordEmail>` component in the `renderToStaticMarkup` function, TypeScript is treating it as a value instead of a type.

to fix this error, you can try **importing** the `ResetPasswordEmail` component as a type using the **typeof keyword**.

Here's an example:

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";
import { sendEmail } from "@/infra/email";
import { ResetPasswordEmail } from "@/infra/email/templates";
import { userRoutes } from "@/routes";

interface SendPasswordResetLink {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  passwordResetToken: string;
}

export const sendPasswordResetLink = async ({ email, firstName, passwordResetToken }: SendPasswordResetLink): Promise<void> => {
  const url = userRoutes.resetPassword.generateUrl(passwordResetToken);
  const subject = `Password reset`;
  const html = renderToStaticMarkup(<typeof ResetPasswordEmail>{ firstName, url });
  const result = await sendEmail({ html, subject, toEmail: email, toName: firstName });

  //... more code
};
```

this example, used the **typeof** keyword to import the `ResetPasswordEmail` component as a **type**. also passed the `firstName` and `url` props directly to the component using object shorthand notation.

and you can also try using the `renderToString` function instead of `renderToStaticMarkup`. `renderToString` is a **server-side** rendering function that is designed to work with Next.js.

here's is:

```
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { sendEmail } from "@/infra/email";
import { ResetPasswordEmail } from "@/infra/email/templates";
import { userRoutes } from "@/routes";

interface SendPasswordResetLink {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  passwordResetToken: string;
}

export const sendPasswordResetLink = async ({ email, firstName, passwordResetToken }: SendPasswordResetLink): Promise<void> => {
  const url = userRoutes.resetPassword.generateUrl(passwordResetToken);
  const subject = `Password reset`;
  const html = renderToString(<ResetPasswordEmail firstName={firstName} url={url} />);
  const result = await sendEmail({ html, subject, toEmail: email, toName: firstName });

  //... more code
};
```

in this example, used the `renderToString` function to render the `ResetPasswordEmail` component to a **string**. also passed the `firstName` and `url` props directly to the component using object shorthand notation.